# The order of a matrix and its eigenvalues.

Tags: linear-algebra, analysis, inverse

Suppose we have a family of intervitble  matrices $\{M_\epsilon\}_{\epsilon>0} \subset \mathbb{R}^{d\times d}$ , for which $M_\epsilon $ is $O(\epsilon)$, which is to say there exists a constant $C$ such that $(M_\epsilon)_{i,j} \leq C \epsilon,$ for all $i,j=1,\ldots, d$. What can we say about the eigenvalues of $M_\epsilon^{-1}$ ? will they be $O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$.

Answer attempt :

If we know $(M_\epsilon^{-1})_{i,j}=O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ for all $i,j=1,\ldots,d$ then for any eigenvalue $\lambda$ of $M_\epsilon^{-1}$

$$
\lambda \leq \| M^{-1}_\epsilon\|_{op}\leq \sup_{x~:~\|x\|=1}\|A\|_2\|x\|=\|A\|_2\leq d \max_{i,j}(M_\epsilon^{-1})_{i,j}=O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})
$$

where $\|\cdot\|_{op}$ is the operator norm and $\|\cdot\|_2$ the 2 norm. $\textbf{But}$ is it obvious that $(M_\epsilon^{-1})_{i,j}=O(\frac{1}{\epsilon})$ just because $(M_\epsilon )_{i,j}=O(\epsilon)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $Av=\lambda v$ then $\frac{1}{\lambda}v=A^{-1}v$. So eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are inverse of those of $A$.

If $|A_{ij}|<\epsilon$ then $||Av||<C\epsilon||v||$ (for some $C$ depending on the order or the matrix) so eigenvalues of such an $A$ are bounded **above** by $C\epsilon$. Therefore eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are bounded **below** by $1/C\epsilon$.